# How do I perform a common function before requesting *any* web page?

Tags: python, flask

Lets say that I have the following

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import config
import utils

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # call utils.function_foo(app)
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/about/")
def about():
    # call utils.function_foo(app)
    return render_template("about.html")

# ... more endpoint handling

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What I want to do is perform `function_foo` before each routing function has a chance to `return`.

```
@app.before_request
def function_foo(app):
    # Something foo'ey.
```

Is not the solution since this calls `function_foo` every time the server gets *any* HTTP request.

This means that if I request the *about* page, and it has 30 images, js files, css files, etc that it has to request, then `function_foo` will be called 31 times before the about page is loaded. I want `function_foo` to be called once in this case, not 31.

If anyone knows a thing about this, then I would greatly appreciate some information on it.

Cheers!

Comment: What is the purpose of `function_foo`?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, `function_foo`  is for Asset Management. I want function foo to recompile all of my SASS if I'm running in a development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a function before or after the route function, you can write your own decorator.

It seams that you don't really want that:

> What I want to do is perform `function_foo` before each routing function **has a chance to return**.

If you want to call `function_foo` before the rendering, you can write your own rendering function:

```
def my_rendering(*args, **kwargs):
    function_foo()
    return render_template(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Agreed... This is the simplest solution for your problem.

Comment: Excellent! The simplicity of this makes me wonder why I didn't even bother thinking of it before.